# How to access an object in database thread-safe

Tags: c#, sql, database, multithreading, wcf

EDIT: Realized that I might have to rethink the design of the system.

I have a WCF-service that accesses an MSSQLDB. In the database there are a number of "objects" saved. I need to be able to access the database multithreaded, but each object thread-safe! And I need to do this in the WCF service.

I know it is possible to do this with isolation levels in the database, but I want to manage as much as possible in the application. The reason for this is to keep all business logic in the application. So it doesn't really matter that it's a database, it could be a static collection of some sort.

Fx. a collection of these objects:

- Object1
- Object2
- Object3

Multiple threads should be able to access the collection at all times, but only one thread at a time should access Object1. A thread won't access multiple objects, so there shouldn't be any risk of deadlocking.

I could do some workaround with managing a lot of singletons, by some kind of id, but I think that would add a lot of overhead.

I also thought of adding a bit in the database for if the object is being accessed, but then I would have to implement some waiting method in the application, and if something went wrong, there is a risk, the thread would hang indefinitely.

Comment: My simple advice is 'don't do this'. Pessimistic locking is hard to get right, and easy to get wrong.

Comment: Instead, I'd look at ways of writing your update logic such that it detects inconsistencies (e.g. timestamps or snapshot isolation).

Comment: The problem is that I need to access an object, check for some stuff, and then execute some other code. All this is concidered business logic. I could do it with transactions, but all this happens across different controllers, that use different data-access-objects.

Comment: Sure. But I am suggesting this is harder than you think. Let's say you implement locking. You get object1 and lock it. You also need some data from object2. But, it turns out my request / thread already has object2 locked. So your thread sites and waits. Now my thread decides it needs object1. Deadlock time!

Comment: Ah each thread won't access multiple objects. If a thread is accessing Object1 it will not access any other objects. BUT there could be multiple threads that want to access Object1.

Comment: And once you lock Object1 - what are you going to do in the end? Update Object1? Update something else?

Comment: Not directly. If a check comes back positive, I'm going to add some related rows in another table. The problem is between the check and adding the rows. Cause if there are rows already added, the check should come back negative. So with multithreading, the check could be wrong.

Comment: A single web server for now, but it should be scaleable in the future.

Comment: Then you'll likely need to use something like https://redis.io/topics/distlock .